# How To Deploy Angular 8 Project to Server cpanel

Tags: node.js, mongodb, deployment, angular8, cpanel

I have developed one application using angular 8 and nodejs(MEAN) for website.Tested in my local server, working perfectly.But i do not know how to deploy in cpanel(I have cpanel access).

Please help anyone to find solution.

My folder structure is like below:

myproject - main folder name:

[image]

client - (angular application)

[image]

server - (NodeJS script)

[image]

Comment: Does your hosting provider support nodejs ? If so.. there would be instruuctions on how to deploy them. Please check that..

Comment: For angular code.. if you do a `ng build`, you would get a `dist` folder which should be placed in the cpanel and most things would be taken care. Any exceptional cases or things you need to config as per ur code base should be done extra.